# Javascript events when modal window is opened or closed

Tags: control-panel, garnish, modal

How can I detect when a modal window has been opened or closed?

I am writing a plugin which wants to detect when a garnish elementeditor modal window has been opened or closed.

Comment: This would be very helpful for some Commerce UI stuff as well...was trying to do this the other day and hit a bit of a wall with it.

Ideally all the modals would be detectable and have a unique class name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if there is no clean way to do this. The solution I am using to detect a new modal is

- detect double click on the element
- wait a second until the modal has opened
- find the modal which is actually open

Like this:

```
$('body').on('dblclick', 'div.element.small', function() {
  window.setTimeout(function(event) {
    // get our modal (there may be several, only one is displayed)
    var $modalContainer = $('div.hud[style*="display: block;"]');
    if ($modalContainer.length) {
      // we have a new modal, do our thing
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

To detect a modal closing:

- use `window.setInterval` for polling (I needed that anyway)
- check whether the modal container is still `display: block`. (I have hold of something in the container, and so I look outward from there.)
- if not, the modal has closed

Like this:

```
if (! $somethingInTheModal.closest('div.hud[style*="display: block;"]').length) {
  // our modal is closed
}
```

By no means ideal, but it seems to be working at the moment for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I ended up doing:

https://github.com/nystudio107/disclosedassets/blob/master/resources/js/disclosedassets.js

There is a `Garnish.Modal.visibleModal` that will contain the handle to the Garnish modal object if one is visible. You can use this to see if a modal is visible, and even see which one.

Unfortunately there's no *event* I'm aware of that triggers when a modal is shown, so you'll still have to poll via `window.setTimeout()` -- it's a hack, but...